# PHP SimpleXML leads to Servererror 500

Tags: php, simplexml

I just want to read out the google weather api xml with that code but it returns a 500. Any ideas why?

```
<?php
 $url = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Moskva&hl=en";
 $xml = simplexml_load_string(utf8_encode(file_get_contents($url)));
 echo $xml->weather->current_conditions->temp_c->attributes()->data;
?>
```

Comment: Works for me without any errors .... whats in the log ? outputs "2" but can print_r the entire `$xml`

Comment: What happens when you start to comment lines out?  What happens when you just call file get contents on the url?  What happens when you try to debug this code?

Comment: everything is ok untill I do that echo $xml->weather->current_conditions->temp_c->attributes()->data;

Comment: @user1005619 change the echo line to just `print_r($xml);` what does that return ?

Comment: Why all the downvoting ? would all the downvoters at least comment ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate the lines out and introduce a try / catch block as follows :

```
try {
  $url = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Moskva&hl=en";
  $temp1 = file_get_contents($url);
  $temp2 = utf8_encode($temp1);
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($temp2);
  echo $xml->weather->current_conditions->temp_c->attributes()->data;
} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

what happens then ?

**Updated**

Your response was due to the ip address your are coming from .... this was the response :

`http://www.google.com/sorry/?continue=http://www.google.com/ig/api%3Fweather%3DMoskva%26hl%3Den`

typing the response URL into a browser gives this :

> Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network.
>   This page checks to see if it's really you sending the requests, and
>   not a robot. Why did this happen?
>
> IP address: 90.214.41.66 Time: 2012-01-06T21:35:24Z URL:
>   http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Moskva&hl=en

Enter the URL in a browser and complete the CAPTCHA - should be sorted then

Comment: Can you a) add the whole source from that page to your question ... b) check your web server / php log files for errors and post them to your question

Comment: a) this is the whole src b) how do i do that? its a paid server but i dont think i have acces to them

Comment: OK - first try commenting everyline out except the file_get_contents line and see if this gives you the problem still - try to identify which line is giving you the error

Comment: ok sorry .. can you try my other suggestion - changing the echo line to just be `print_r($xml);`

Comment: returns nothing but site loads

Comment: OK - now add this `var_dump($http_response_header);` after the file_get_contents line it will show the response headers - your request is either not getting to the remote site because its been blocked or your request is being rejected by the remote site

Comment: Your IP seems to be blocked .... read my updated answer ... after clicking on the link it provided i was prompted with a CATPCHA - i completed that and it looks like its fixed your problem !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your PHP configuration.

I just run the code and I get '2' as a result. No 500 error page.

Answer (score 0):

It can definitely be a configuration. We have two servers, one local, and one develop / staging. Running only one line of code to get the RSS XML data, it works just fine on local, but gives 500 on staging. It's definitely a server configuration issue.